# C++ : ((A*)nullptr)->foo(); is legal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

While digging deep into MFC, I found this code:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE HWND CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() const
    { return this == NULL ? NULL : m_hWnd; }
```

It seems to be used in this way.

```
CWnd *pWnd = nullptr;
pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(); // NULL
pWnd = /* something */;
pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(); // window handle
```

At this point, I've got confused - we're now calling a member function with **NULL** object! How can it be legal C++?

Comment: It's not legal C++. OTOH, MFC presumably knows that Microsoft's compiler won't do anything crazy.

Comment: In theory (by standard) it is undefined behavior. That could mean everything from the world comes crashing down to nothing bad happens whatsoever. You are just passing a nullptr to a function that doesn't use it or reference any of the alleged object's members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the plainest of undefined behavior as far as the language is concerned. §9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static]/p2:

> If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object
>   that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior
>   is undefined.

Presumably, whoever wrote this function knows that Microsoft's compiler won't do anything crazy in this particular case, as being "safe" to call on a null `CWnd *` appears to be the whole point for its existence(!).

Comment: But the member function isn't called for *any* object, so the quote doesn't apply, does it?

Comment: @Loopunroller Well, I'd argue that the intention is to make it UB for all cases except the one allowed in 9.3.1/p1 ("A non-static member function may be called for an object of its class type, or for an object of a class derived (Clause 10) from its class type...", but if you think p2 doesn't cover it directly, then it falls under "what's not defined is undefined", since the standard doesn't define what happens when you call a non-static member function without anything.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry, but isn't this about calling a method from a null pointer to an X object rather than from a different type?

Comment: @claudv - you don't really "call from the pointer" unless it is a virtual call, in the case of "static calls" `object.foo()` is equivalent to `object_foo(&object)` and is what the C++ compiler does behind the scene for you.

Comment: @ddriver that is almost certainly true, yet irrelevant!  What the C++ compiler does beyond the specifications of the C++ standard is undefined by the standard.  The standard makes the call undefined, and lets the compiler do what it chooses.  As it happens, the easiest way to implement C++ method calls ends up being basically what you describe, and almost every C++ implementation does that.  The C++ language standard does not, however, MANDATE that.  And more critically, the compiler is free to instrument builds to detect null pointer dereferencing to aid in debugging, and halt execution.